# Power BI Conditional Format with Dynamic Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

Team -
The matrix table created is designed to be dynamic in that a user can select any time frame from the 'Focus Period' and any time from the 'Compare Period' and the correspond measure (count of widgets) for each is displayed ... along with the delta in number and percentage.

[image]

I would like to format the percentage based on rules however the dialog box for conditional formatting does not allow me to choose the measure.

[image]

I've been researching and testing but am unable to find a solution.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with my measure being dynamic and that conditional formatting cannot be done through the dialog box but maybe via DAX.

The percentage measure itself is based off two other measures.  The first one captures the count of widgets for the Focus Period and the second measure captures the count of widgets for the Compare Period.  And finally, the calculation to derive the percentage.

**Focus Period Measure** = CALCULATE(Measure_Table[Measure],FILTER(Wk_Wk,Wk_Wk[fisc_quarter_val]=[Focus Period Dynamic Time]))

**Compare Period Measure** = CALCULATE(Measure_Table[Measure],FILTER(Wk_Wk,Wk_Wk[fisc_quarter_val]=[Compare Period Dynamic Time]))

**Delta_Percent** = FORMAT(((Measure_Table[Compare Period Measure] - Measure_Table[Focus Period Measure])/Measure_Table[Focus Period Measure]),"0.0%")

Simply, if the percentage <0 THEN red

if the percentage is 0 to .25 THEN black

ELSE green

Anyone else tackle this yet?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new measure as

```
Delta_Percent_Color = IF([Delta_Percent] > 0.25, "#40FF40", IF([Delta_Percent] > 0, "#000000, "#FF6060")))
```

2. Choose `Field Value` as the Format Style and give `Delta_Percent_Color` as the Field.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: @Kotana Sai:  what version of Power BI are you using?  I'm not seeing what your describing.  I'm on:  Version: 2.112.1161.0 64-bit

Comment: I have: Version: 2.117.984.0 64-bit (May, 2023)

Comment: In your screenshot above, where you have selected "Rules", you should see `Gradient", "Rules", and "Field value". Select the later.